# Trying to connect to prismic got "getFirst is not a function"

Tags: node.js, express, prismic.io

So I'm running an app with nodejs + express, and trying to connect to the prismic API. The documentation is using the ESM, but I want to do it using CommonJS, when I finished the config and tried to run the app, I got the error getFirst is not a function, and I am suspecting that could be in the way I declared the export client to "module.export.client". But because I am not familiar with this so I am not 100% sure.

So at the moment my app.js file looks like this

```
require('dotenv').config()


const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const path = require('path')
const port = 3000
const client = require('./config/prismicConfig.js')

//Prismic
const prismic = require('@prismicio/client')
const prismicH = require('@prismicio/helpers')
const fetch = require('node-fetch')


const repoName = 'my-repo-name'
const accessToken = process.env.PRISMIC_ACCESS_TOKEN 
const endpoint = prismic.getEndpoint(repoName) 

const routes = [
    {
        type:'page',
        path:'/'
    }
]

module.exports.client =  prismic.createClient(endpoint, { 
    fetch, 
    accessToken,
    routes,
  })

//Prismic



//  template engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname,'views'))
app.set('view engine', 'pug')



//Middleware
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.ctx = {
      prismicH,
    }
    next()
  })
  //end



app.get('/', async (req, res) => {

  const document = await client.getFirst()
  res.render('page', { document })

})

app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(` Example listen to http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

And this is my prismicConfig.js

```
require('dotenv').config()
console.log(process.env.PRISMIC_ENDPOINT, process.env.PRISMIC_CLIENT_ID)

const fetch = require ('node-fetch')
const prismic = require ('@prismicio/client')

const repoName = 'my-repo-name' 
const accessToken = process.env.PRISMIC_ACCESS_TOKEN 
const endpoint = prismic.getEndpoint(repoName) 


const routes = [
  {
    type: 'page',
    path: '/',
  },
]

module.exports.client = prismic.createClient(endpoint, { 
  fetch, 
  accessToken,
  routes,
})
```

So I will appreciate an advice on this. In advance thank you for reading me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated in your post, you're not using the default export, but a named export `module.exports.client` in prismicConfig.js.

Which means that the consumer of this module, app.js, needs to destructure the `client` property :

```js
const { client } = require('./config/prismicConfig')
```

Answer (score 2):

it's `client.client` then, so you should require it like so:

```
const {client} = require('./config/prismicConfig.js')
```

also, you don't need prismic setup in the server/app.js, as it's in the config already:

try changing app.js like so:

```
require('dotenv').config()


const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const path = require('path')
const port = 3000
const prismicH = require('@prismicio/helpers')
const {client} = require('./config/prismicConfig.js')


//  template engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname,'views'))
app.set('view engine', 'pug')



//Middleware
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.ctx = {
      prismicH,
    }
    next()
  })
  //end



app.get('/', async (req, res) => {

  const document = await client.getFirst()
  res.render('page', { document })

})

app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(` Example listen to http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Comment: Hello @traynor thank you, thank you, very much :) for take the time and look up at the whole code, this is very helpful, I was actually asking me the same, because in the official doc is appearing twice, this make more sense.